# Combining a page map with a PDF so that annotations move with pages in updated PDFs

Tags: pdf, annotations

Has anyone managed to provide an end-user with an updated PDF, allowing that user to transfer his local annotations to the new PDF and keeping the annotations on the correct page, even when there are pages inserted into the update PDF at a point earlier in the PDF than the annotations.

I thought there might be a page map or page guid approach that someone has used.

Sorry - I hope that is clear.

Comment: As annotations are directly associated with their respective page object, why should the insertion of another page before or after this page make any difference? Maybe I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you should provide sample documents.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Here is the full sequence:

1. I am sent a 50 page PDF document.
2. I add an annotation on page 25.
3. I am sent an update to the PDF document.  The update is a 51 page PDF document.  Each page is identical apart from an extra page, which has been inserted after the 2nd page.
4. I transfer my annotation to the new PDF.  It goes on the 25th page, which now contains different content to my previous PDF.
5. My annotation is now on the 'wrong' page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the page index as ID of the page, you can use the page content stream instead (after decoding/decompression). Most PDF libraries will give you access to that, so you could compute an MD5 hash from the page content and search for that instead on your "updated" file in order to know where to transfer your annotations.

This is assuming that the page content will be indeed identical, which is not a common scenario.

Comment: The page content stream may well be identical (e.g. in case of scanned documents, one image respectively may be positioned on each page, and its respective XObject name might always be the same). Thus, I would propose adding explicit page markers instead.

Comment: @mkl You are right, I missed that case. But if the OP is not generating the original documents how is he going to add page markers?

Comment: True. Well, maybe he can either guarantee that the PDFs in question do not have identical content streams, and then use your recommendation, or he can adapt the process to allow an initial page marking step in the process...